# how to create Floating window in android

Tags: android

I saw some android applications that has floating window like something in windows OS (or like picture below).I had searched but i could not find any thing.Is any api or library needed or this is just styling?

[image: Floating window in android]

Comment: These  are all appwidgets. try googling with appwidget. you may find something

Comment: are you sure.it is on screen on all other applications.

Comment: Those really don't look like App Widgets to me. You can do that, however, using a `Dialog` theme on Activities, and directly manipulating their `Window`s' attributes and layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You can build App Widgets. App Widgets are miniature application views that can be embedded in other applications (such as the Home screen) and receive periodic update

go to link for more details 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html